# Get the value of clicked Item of a custom listview?

Tags: android

I have created a Custom listview and set data by parsing a link and sorted them inside the list. Now when I am going to make a click and get the value of the individual object of a row I can't get the object of clicked row.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnChildClickListener,
        OnItemClickListener {
    private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
    private List<GroupEntity> mGroupCollection;
    String URL;
    ArrayList<EventParsingClass> EventObject_Collection = new ArrayList<EventParsingClass>();
    ArrayList<Date> DateArray = new ArrayList<Date>();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<EventParsingClass>> arrayOfEventDescription = new ArrayList<ArrayList<EventParsingClass>>();

    MyListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.event_mainactivity);
        prepareResource();
        initPage();

        URL = "http://..............";

        ParsingWithURL(URL);

    }

    private void ParsingWithURL(String uRL2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new JSONPARSINGFOREVENTSTREAM().execute(URL);

    }

    private class JSONPARSINGFOREVENTSTREAM extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private final String TAG_ID = "id";
        private final String TAG_Title = "title";
        private final String TAG_Description = "description";
        private final String TAG_StartDate = "start_datetime";
        private final String TAG_EndDate = "end_datetime";
        private final String TAG_City = "place_city";
        private final String TAG_Club = "place_club";
        private final String TAG_AgeLimit = "event_agelimit";
        private static final String TAG_Event_streamable = "data";

        EventParsingClass EPC;
        JSONArray streamable = null;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.d("************PARAMS", arg0[0]);

            JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jparser.getJSONFromUrl(arg0[0]);

            try {
                streamable = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Event_streamable);

                for (int i = 0; i < streamable.length(); i++) {
                    EPC = new EventParsingClass();
                    JSONObject c = streamable.getJSONObject(i);
                    EPC.setId(c.getString(TAG_ID));
                    EPC.setPlace_city(c.getString(TAG_City));
                    EPC.setPlace_club(c.getString(TAG_Club));
                    EPC.setTitle(c.getString(TAG_Title));
                    EPC.setDescription(c.getString(TAG_Description));
                    EPC.setSratdate_time(c.getString(TAG_StartDate));
                    EPC.setEnddate_time(c.getString(TAG_EndDate));
                    EPC.setEvent_agelimit(c.getString(TAG_AgeLimit));

                    long difference = EPC.geEnddate_time_date().getTime()
                            - EPC.getSratdate_time_date().getTime();

                    int day_difference = (int) (difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

                    // Log.d("Difference", "" + day_difference);

                    if (day_difference == 0) {

                        AddDay(EPC.getSratdate_time_date());

                    } else {

                        if (DateArray.size() == 0) {

                            DateArray.add(EPC.getSratdate_time_date());

                            long startday = EPC.getSratdate_time_date()
                                    .getTime();

                            for (int k = 1; k <= day_difference; k++) {

                                long constructedday = startday
                                        + (1000 * 3600 * 24) * k;

                                Date Constructed_value = new Date(
                                        constructedday);

                                DateArray.add(Constructed_value);
                            }

                        } else {

                            AddDay(EPC.getSratdate_time_date());

                            long startday = EPC.getSratdate_time_date()
                                    .getTime();

                            for (int k = 1; k <= day_difference; k++) {

                                long constructedday = startday
                                        + (1000 * 3600 * 24) * k;

                                Date Constructed_value = new Date(
                                        constructedday);

                                AddDay(Constructed_value);
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    EventObject_Collection.add(EPC);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        private void AddDay(Date value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (DateArray.size() == 0) {
                DateArray.add(value);
            } else {
                boolean b = true;
                for (Date s : DateArray) {
                    if (s.equals(value)) {

                        b = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (b) {
                    DateArray.add(value);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Log.d("+++++++++++++++++++++++number of Items in List", ""
                    + DateArray.size());
            AddDetailedItemToListView();
            AddHeaderItemsToListView();
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

        private void AddDetailedItemToListView() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            for (Date s : DateArray) {

                ArrayList<EventParsingClass> constructed_arrayfor_items = new ArrayList<EventParsingClass>();

                for (int g = 0; g < EventObject_Collection.size(); g++) {

                    EventParsingClass EVPC = EventObject_Collection.get(g);
                    long new_startdate = EVPC.getSratdate_time_date().getTime();
                    long new_endtdate = EVPC.geEnddate_time_date().getTime();
                    long date = s.getTime();

                    if (date >= new_startdate && date <= new_endtdate) {

                        Log.d("^^^^^^^^^^^ Value Of Date  ", "" + s);
                        Log.d("^^^^^^^^^^^ Value Of StartDay ",
                                "" + EVPC.getSratdate_time_date());
                        Log.d("^^^^^^^^^^^ Value Of EndDay ",
                                "" + EVPC.geEnddate_time_date());

                        constructed_arrayfor_items.add(EVPC);

                    }
                }
                arrayOfEventDescription.add(constructed_arrayfor_items);

                Log.d("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^arrayOfEventDescription", ""
                        + arrayOfEventDescription);
            }

        }

        private void AddHeaderItemsToListView() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_evevnt);

            LayoutInflater i = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);

            List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
            int length_of_datearray = DateArray.size();

            Log.d("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "" + DateArray.size());
            Log.d("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE", "" + arrayOfEventDescription.size());

            for (ArrayList<EventParsingClass> It : arrayOfEventDescription) {
                Log.d("", "" + It.size());

                for (EventParsingClass oETC : It) {
                    Log.d("*******" + oETC.getTitle(),
                            "" + oETC.getSratdate_time_date());
                }

            }

            for (int m = 0; m < length_of_datearray; m++) {

                String day_of_header = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat
                        .format("EEEE", DateArray.get(m));
                String month_of_header = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat
                        .format("MMM", DateArray.get(m));
                String date_of_header = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat
                        .format("dd", DateArray.get(m));

                String total_header = day_of_header + " " + month_of_header
                        + " " + date_of_header;

                items.add(new Header(i, "" + total_header));

                ArrayList<EventParsingClass> Arraylist_for_loop = arrayOfEventDescription
                        .get(m);

                for (int h = 0; h < Arraylist_for_loop.size(); h++) {

                    String description = Arraylist_for_loop.get(h).getId();
                    String title = Arraylist_for_loop.get(h).getTitle();

                    String place_city = Arraylist_for_loop.get(h)
                            .getPlace_city();

                    String age_limit = Arraylist_for_loop.get(h)
                            .getEvent_agelimit();

                    String dayOfTheWeek = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat
                            .format("EEEE", Arraylist_for_loop.get(h)
                                    .getSratdate_time_date());

                    String DayofWeek = dayOfTheWeek;

                    if (!(dayOfTheWeek == day_of_header)) {

                        DayofWeek = day_of_header;
                    }

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
                    Date d = new Date();
                    String Today = sdf.format(d);

                    String Value_of_today = "";

                    if (Today.contentEquals(DayofWeek)) {

                        Value_of_today = "Today";
                    }

                    items.add(new EventItem(i, Value_of_today, DayofWeek,
                            "12:00", title, description, place_city, "10",
                            age_limit));

                }

            }
            MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

    }

    private void prepareResource() {

        mGroupCollection = new ArrayList<GroupEntity>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            GroupEntity ge = new GroupEntity();
            ge.Name = "City " + i;

            for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
                GroupItemEntity gi = ge.new GroupItemEntity();
                gi.Name = "Venu" + j;
                ge.GroupItemCollection.add(gi);
            }

            mGroupCollection.add(ge);
        }

    }

    private void initPage() {
        mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        ExpandableListAdapter adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,
                mExpandableListView, mGroupCollection);

        mExpandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), childPosition + "Clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {


            EventParsingClass obj = (EventParsingClass) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  obj.getPlace_city() + "Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

How can I proceed in these two scenarios?

`EventParsingClass EPSP= ???` and

`EPSP.getid= ??`

Comment: please let me know is this working or not !!

Answer (score 1):

```
fetch[0]="XXX"
fetch[1]="YYY"
fetch[2]="ZZZ"

lv.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fetch[position] + "Clicked",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

just declare **fetch[position]** to get the value of clicked item. hope this will give you some solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
EventItem item = (EventItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Now you have a hold of `EventItem`. So you can start using the `get` methods of your `EventItem` class in order to get whatever you want from it.

Comment: You are attaching "items" to your "ListView". So do the same approach I have you as an answer. But instead of CustomClass you change it to EventItem, because your "items" consists of "EventItem" objects.

Comment: you CANT do that, you need to understand how listview works. You are attaching EventItem objects to it, not EventParsingClass. In your case, you will have to create a EventParsingClass variable inside EventItem in order to get it. Or change your items to be EventParsingClass objects.

Comment: I have done this ....Now how can i get the Object EventParsing class corresponding Iteam... ???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32572/discussion-between-nrahman-and-carnal)

Answer (score 0):

Use int position to find out values from your data list (array list or what ever you used).

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  EPSP.getid(position) + "Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: I have Tried this and giving Force Close :                                         EventParsingClass obj = (EventParsingClass) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
  
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  obj.getPlace_city() + "Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: @NRahman EPSP is a filled object of any collection ? Its a data provider from which you are filling your list.  Its similar what  Nirmal said.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
EventParsingClass new_method(int value) {

int item_count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfEventDescription.size(); i++) {

    ArrayList<EventParsingClass> Arraylist_for_loop = arrayOfEventDescription
            .get(i);

    item_count++;
    for (int j = 0; j < Arraylist_for_loop.size(); j++) {

        if (value == item_count) {

            return Arraylist_for_loop.get(j);
        }

        item_count++;

    }

}

return null;

}
```

And call it from here:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        EventParsingClass newObject = new_method(arg2);

        if (newObject == null) {

        } else {
            Log.d("Generated Value Id : ", "" + newObject.getId());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Item Clicked" + arg2 + "-----" + newObject.getTitle(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```